# How could I make the "percent sign" searchable in .CHM?

Tags: chm, html-help-workshop

We use strings with "percent sign" like "%abc" or abc%def" or "xyz%" in our HTML files. We compile with htmlhelp workshop. We see the  "percent sign" in the compiled CHM, but they are not searchable. Also the search with placeholder ?abc does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the full textsearch facility indexer strips all non alphabetic characters.

Comment: thanks marco, and do you know how i could configure the indexer?

Comment: AFAIK adding a full-text search stop list to a help Project is possible only.